# Is there a way to post data to the server by passing an object or form?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm creating an example of posting a form to the server and I would like to just send an object or form to the server but the only examples I've found show manually creating the post variables like a query string:

For example [1]:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford"); // can I pass in an object here?
```

The problems I see with this are that I have to manually add each form item one after another. I have over a 100 form items. How do I handle file attachements? Do I need to manually encode the form element values too?

I do ***not*** want to use JQuery.

**Update:** Here is what is sent when the form is sent using FormData as suggested:

```
-----------------------------1663011888741135911866103577 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id" 

435 
-----------------------------1663011888741135911866103577 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="slug"


-----------------------------1663011888741135911866103577 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nonce" 

1ef7445783 
-----------------------------1663011888741135911866103577 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title" 

Updated title 
-----------------------------1663011888741135911866103577 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content" 

updated content 
-----------------------------1663011888741135911866103577 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message" 

Updating post... 
-----------------------------1663011888741135911866103577--
```

Here is the code for the above service call above:

```
function updatePost() {
    if (postId==null) { return alert("Please create a post before calling update post"); }
    var request = getRequest();
    document.getElementById("responseTextArea").value = "Updating post...";

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var query = "/blog/?json=posts/update_post";

        if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var formValues = "nonce="+json.nonce+"&title=UpdatedPost" + "&content=Content" + "&id="+postId;
            var newRequest = getRequest();
            document.getElementById("nonce").value = json.nonce;
            document.getElementById("id").value = postId;
            document.getElementById("slug").value = slug;
            query += "&id=" + postId;
            console.log(query);
            var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('myForm'));

            newRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (newRequest.readyState==4 && newRequest.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("responseTextArea").value = newRequest.responseText;
                }
            }

            // now that we have our token post data back to the server
            newRequest.open("POST", query, true);
            newRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            newRequest.send(form);
        }
    }

    // get token first
    request.open("GET","/blog/?json=get_nonce&controller=posts&method=update_post", true);
    request.send();
}

<div id="mainContent" style="width:500px;position:relative;display:block;margin:0 auto;">
    <p>
        <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="slug" id="slug"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="nonce" id="nonce"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="title" id="title" value="Updated title"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="content" id="content" value="updated content"/>
            <button type="button" onclick="getData('/blog/?json=info')">Get JSON API Info</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="getData('/blog/?json=get_recent_posts')">Get Recent Posts</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="createPost()">Create Post</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="updatePost()">Update Post</button>
            <br/><textarea id="responseTextArea" type="text" name="message" style="width: 100%;height:300px"></textarea><br/><br/>
        </form>
    </p>
</div>
```

[1] http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of arguments which an XMLHttpRequest object will accept is as follows:

```
void send();
void send(ArrayBufferView data);
void send(Blob data);
void send(Document data);
void send(DOMString? data);
void send(FormData data);
```

To use the FormData option:

```
var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById("my-form-id") );
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

---

Edit - info from OP:

It appears that when you pass in a formData that uses the form rather than a form element, it uses the method that the form specifies not the method specified in the open() call. When I set the method in the form to "POST" instead of leaving it blank it worked

Comment: It seems to be sending the form but the server is saying it's not finding the variable. I'm passing in the formData. Firebug reports the results:

Comment: I see two variables listed in the data from your update; `nonce` = `'85abdd0b92'` and `title` = `'New title'`. Is there another variable which is missing?

Comment: I think so. One was named content (I've since changed the code). I'll test it again. It looks like part of it is missing? Does it make sense that the long string of characters is all the same on each line?

Comment: Would form values posted using the FormData be accessed differently on the server? For example, would they no longer be in $_REQUEST (PHP)?

Comment: That long string of characters is the field separator - the same string appears between each field of the post. Make sure each your form inputs has the name specified. Inputs without a name won't get posted.

Comment: It appears that when you pass in a formData that uses the **form** rather than a **form element**, it uses the **method** that the **form** specifies not the method specified in the **open()** call. When I set the method in the form to "POST" instead of leaving it blank it worked. Please add this information to your answer I'll select it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the elements in your form by using: `form.getElementsByTagName('input')` or better yet `form.elements`

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: why the downvote? yes this is old technology but it does what he asks

using web forms it is relatively straight forward

```
<form action="iceCream.php>
   <input name="favouriteIceCream"/>
   <input name="favouriteTopping"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

when the user clicks the submit button a request will be sent like this

```
POST iceCream.php
     favouriteIceCream=chocolate&favouriteTopping=sprinkles
```